# How do I cache global NPM packages on Travis CI?

Tags: ubuntu, continuous-integration, npm, travis-ci

Locally installed packages are cached via:

```
# .travis.yml
...
cache:
  directories:
  - node_modules
...
```

But how do I cache globally installed packages (`$ npm install -g <...>`) to speed up my builds?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
cache:
  directories:
    # Replace "grunt-cli" with whatever global binary you're using
    - $(npm config get prefix)/bin/grunt-cli
```

EDIT:

As was pointed out in the comments, `$(npm config get prefix)/bin` contains symlinks to other code. This is untested but would probably work: `$(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules`. That should cache *all* globally installed modules.

Comment: I'm also avoiding reinstall to save more time: 
`npm list -g grunt-cli --depth=0 || npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: Yeah, me too. It would be nice if travis would just skip installs of cached things. Alas.

Comment: Isn't `$(npm config get prefix)/bin/grunt-cli` a mere symlink to a binary? How does it make sense to cache it? I've tried to add `$(npm config get prefix)` to the cache directories but travis fails to fetch the cache on subsequent builds still.

Comment: Thanks @stefanjunker, yeah, that doesn't make a ton of sense. I'll update.