# Cache global node_modules on travis in the correct directory

Tags: gruntjs, travis-ci

I'm using grunt-cli on travis to execute tests. It's installed globally during the install step like this:

```
install:
  # amongst other install steps
  - npm list -g grunt-cli --depth=0 || npm install -g grunt-cli
```

and then I'm caching it, like this, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240237/how-do-i-cache-global-npm-packages-on-travis-ci) (which, incidentally, I answered):

```
cache:
  directories:
    - $(npm config get prefix)/bin/grunt-cli
```

However, on the next build, I see this: `tar: /home/travis/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/grunt-cli: Not found in archive`. And the reason is, `grunt-cli` gets cached in `.nvm/v0.10.40/` because that's what version of node is being tested against (mostly by default - we just have `node_js: 0.10` set in the config, so it installs the most recent version). But apparently the starting version of node on travis is 0.10.36. Obviously, there are ways around this, but this seems like extremely naive behavior. I mean, travis does the cache first, then nvm installs the right version of node rendering the initial cache useless. Maybe they just didn't have global node_modules in mind for caching. Is there something I'm missing with configuration? Or should I just `npm config set prefix` to a version-independent path and add it to my `$PATH`? (Or alternatively, use a fully qualified version - major.minor.patch - and hard-code the cache directory?)